# Google Analytics custom dimensions not reporting

Tags: google-analytics, custom-dimensions

The reporting of my custom dimensions is very inconsistent and seemingly just not being reported sometimes, making our reports almost useless. Here is an example.

This is how the GA code is formatted on the page...

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-1', 'auto');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Iowa DOT');
ga('set', 'dimension4', 'editorial');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

and here is what I see in GA.

[image]
[image]

The same exact page, but totally different dimension results. Can anyone shine a light on something I may be missing, or point me an a direction to get this straightened out.

Comment: Getting a really similar situation, except comparing a search for the URL with the results for the same page which should always have the dimension added. It seems there's scenarios where the hit is logged, but the dimension is lost! It feels so random. I'm also hit scoped, and it happens even for reports with 100% sample size.

Answer (score 1):

Are your Custom Dimensions in question Session Scoped or Hit Scope. From your description, I would assume they are Session Scope which is causing the problem. Session Scope custom dimensions are recorded once per session. 
If you add to the report a Session Scope Custom Dimension and use a Hit Scope dimension (such as Page, in your example) instead of a Custom Dimension value set on a current pageview (seems to be your expectation) you would see a value attached to the latest pageview in a session. Practically speaking, results in reports mixing Session and Hit Scoped dimensions could be quite bizarre.

Please check the scope of your Custom dimensions with index 1 and 4. Should be Hit scope if you plan on using it with Page (url) dimension

Comment: They are both 'Hit' scoped.